# Implementing CLI for OSGi Equinox application

Tags: eclipse, command-line-interface, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox

What is a correct way of implementing CLI for Eclipse Equinox Application? How to get any user console input from inside of Equinox-OSGi component to handle it according to application's business logic? Is there a library that already has the described functionality implemented?

Comment: If you mean the OSGI console the section "Console Shell" in the "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide > Runtime overview" section of the Eclipse help describes adding commands to that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom osgi-console commands in Eclipse really easily, and [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-osgiconsole/)'s *Extending the console* section tells in details how to do that.